# What is practiced in C++ to use for byte manipulation uint8 or char?

Tags: c++

I am coming from Java to C++ and I need something similar to `byte[]` from Java. I can use `std::vector<>` for easy array like manipulation but I need answer what is practiced in C++ to use for byte manipulation `uint8` or `char` ? ( I have lot off packing bigger integers in arrays with & 0xff and >> number so it need to be quick)

Comment: There is no such type as `uint8` in C++.

Comment: I wonder why you are using ``uint8``/``char`` if you're packing bigger integers. Is there any reason not to stay in the bigger integer representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `uint8` is an 8 bit unsigned integer type, the main difference on a "normal" C++ implementation is that `char` is not necessarily unsigned.

On "not normal" C++ implementations, there could be more significant differences -- `char` might not be 8 bits. But then, what would you define `uint8` to be on such an implementation anyway?

Whether the sign difference matters or not depends how you're using it, but as a rule of thumb it's best to use unsigned types with bitwise operators. That said, they both get promoted to `int` in bitwise `&` anyway (again on a "normal" C++ implementation) and it really doesn't matter for `&`, it doesn't cause surprises in practice. But using `<<` on a negative signed value results in undefined behavior, so avoid that.

So, use an unsigned type. If the most convenient way for you to write that is `uint8`, and you know that your code deals in octets and will only run on systems where `char` is an octet, then you may as well use it.

If you want to use a standard type, use `unsigned char`. Or `uint8_t` in order to deliberately prevent your code compiling on "not normal" implementations where `char` is not an octet.

Answer (score 1):

C++ reserved words are `char`, `signed char`, and/or `unsigned char`. `uint8` is probably a typedef synonym for `unsigned char`.